# Google Chrome (MacOS) - Command+A does not select all in address bar

Tags: google-chrome, mac, keyboard, shortcuts

I am used to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything in my address bar in Google Chrome. On my new Macbook (running Monterey), the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> shortcut when my address bar is focused but not select - moves me to the right-most tab.

On my other macbook running Big Sur, this does not happen. On my Linux box, this does not happen.

I am not able to find what shortcut the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is in any google searches, and I could not find a similar question being asked here - only one for Linux.

As to why do I need this? I sometimes copy-paste text from a webpage/other-app into the address bar, then copy-paste it from the address bar onto where I want it. This is to avoid formatting from webpages/apps making it onto the place I want to paste it on.

Comment: Try [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/324880/963426).

Comment: For me, if my cursor is in Chrome's URL bar (on macOS), Cmd-A does select the full URL.  In fact, when I click anywhere in the URL bar, the default behaviour is to select the full URL.  But, I can deselect the text, leaving my cursor in the URL bar, and CMD-A does the right thing.  When you say the the URL bar is "focused" what does that mean?  Perhaps include a pic of what you're doing.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Although it doesn't send you to the rightmost tab but to the last tab visited. It happens when you click and focus on the URL bar (or open a new tab), and when the blinking | cursor is on the URL text somewhere and you want to select the text, it sends you to the prev. tab. I have no idea what's going on and it's really annoying. Also happens when you manually in the menubar Edit->Select All. Feels like a bug

Comment: I have same problem here. Any Solution? It's a boring issue!